# How to call more than one array in for loop? AS3

Tags: arrays, for-loop, actionscript-3

Something like this

```
var array1:Array = new Array();
var array2:Array = new Array();

for each (var mc in array1 && mc in array2)
{ trace(mc); }
```

obviously this doesnt work. Ive also tried

```
for each (var mc in array1 || mc in array2)
{ trace(mc); }
```

and

```
for each (var mc in array1)
for each (var mc in array2)
{ trace(mc); }
```

Comment: Use iterator variable **for (var i:int = 0; i < array1.length; i++)** and then address the elements by their indices: **array1[i]** and **array2[i]** respectively.

Comment: On the other thought, if you just need to iterate over all the items in the several **Array**s in a single loop, use **Array.concat(...)** to create a temporary conjoint **Array**.

Comment: English is not a programming language, you need to reform your statements into a form that the computer would understand. Even I didn't understand what did you mean about iterating two arrays in a single loop. Why don't you for example iterate one array in one loop, and the other array in the other loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
var array1:Array = new Array();
var array2:Array = new Array();
int maxLength = 0;
int lengthArray1 = array1.length;
maxLength = lengthArray1;
int lengthArray2 = array2.length;
if (lengthArray2 > maxLength){
    maxLength = lengthArray2;
}
for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++){
    if (lengthArray1 > i){
       trace(array1[i]);
    }
    if (lengthArray2 > i){
       trace(array2[i]);
    }
}
```